# How to append items to the bottom of the table or collection view ?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a swift table view/collection view. Is there anyway I could append items to the end of the container ? Like an upside down stack or something ?

Comment: What do you use to hold the items that you display in table view? If it is an array, then it is the matter of adding the item, at any index you want and just reloading the table view/collection view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need insert rows at in UITableView and collection view for that first need to insert in you data source.
For TableView

```
//Update data source with the object that you need to add
[tableDataSource addObject:newObject];

NSInteger row = [tableDataSource count]-1 ;//specify a row where you need to add new row in your case last
NSInteger section = //specify the section where the new row to be added, 
//section = 0 here since you need to add row at first section

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

For CollectionView

```
    [self.myCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
[collectionDataSource addObject:newObject];
NSInteger row = [collectionDataSource count]-1 ;//specify a row where you need to add new row in your case last
             to add new row in your case last
    NSInteger section = //specify the section where the new row to be added, 
    //section = 0 here since you need to add row at first section

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            [self.myCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        } completion:nil];
```